# How to interpret executable binary file

Tags: exe, binaryfiles, logical-decoding

All these files without extension in Unix and the '.exe' in Windows are great ways to keep programs static; what I'm looking for is an interpretation of its binary content. I mean not to decode the content but to group it in a reliable manner.

Comment: It is an interesting question but the short answer is that "you can't". The binary information is basically the low-level instructions that are implemented by your CPU architecture. They include operations and static data that can't even the distinguished (in general) without more context.

Comment: I been thinking about it. I just don't have references to provide practical knowledge. ---I feel it must be possible to analyze CPU resources to decode the used package encoding. To anything that is not cifrated, at least.

Comment: You can de-compile the binary back to assembler - that is a one-to-one translation. After that there is not anything more you can do in any general sense. If it is a .NET executable then you can probably de-compile it back to C# that will be slightly readable (to a programmer). The reality is that assembler is not very readable and you _could_ work out what is does but it will take you months per file I would expect.